# Intuitive picture for spin-fluctuations contribution to sign reversal of S+- state

Tags: superconductivity, strong-correlated

In conventional superconductor, electron-phonon interactions lead to negative paring potential and further s-wave superconducting gap.

One mechanism for superconductivity in iron-based superconductor is the AFM spin fluctuation which causes electron-paramagnon coupling as a pairing potential. However, this pairing potential is positive and thus giving sign reversal between superconducting gaps at different Fermi pockets.

Is there any intuitive picture behind this positive potential? Why is it positive and why this potential have different sign compared to electron-phonon interaction?